# How can I find a cell in excel which contains certain text I have in a list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

Here I am working with two columns, both the columns have concatenated data present within them. I have examples shown below:

The column from where i need to search the data from-

```
col1
buildingtoysjacknicksharon
watertoysnatealexasamfelix
rctoyssharonsamnate
sciencetoysjackfelixalexa
```

The list-

```
col2
buildingtoyssharon
watertoysaleaxa
rctoysnate
sciencefelix
```

I wanted to do a vlookup of column2 with column 1 but the data in both the columns were not exact, I tried other methods using lookup, search, index, match, countif etc. but could not find a way to  lookup the data from column 2.

I wanted to know if there is a way to return "buildingtoyssharon" from "buildingtoysjacknicksharon" etc.

Comment: Do you have the source data that is being concatenated to generate these strings?

Comment: Yes I have the source data with me.

Comment: @Flinders samuel asher Please post some of it.

Comment: Just getting back to this; since you have the source data, you can `CountIfs()`, or `Match`()` with an array (if you only want the first result).  `CountIfs()` with the source data would be my starting place.